# i have the error make: *** No rule to make target `port-name'. Stop

Tags: installation, imap

when i am trying to execute this command:
make port-name EXTRADRIVERS='' SSLTYPE=none
to install UW IMAP from source
what is wrong;
questions in the internet says that the make file does not have the rule port-name
thanks

Comment: What does your Makefile look like?

Answer (score 0):

Do not install UW-IMAPD. It's 2017, the last release of this IMAP server is from 2011. That's **six years** of missing security, stability, compatibility, performance and feature fixes.

If you're looking for a reasonable open-source free-software zero-cost IMAP server, just install Dovecot and be done with it. It comes with the majority of Linux distros, so it's just one command away, unlike trying to compile an unamaintained, obsolete software.